# Remove the element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code to delete the text box wen the '-' button is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    var id=1,text;
    text = '<li id="input_'+id+'" ><input type="text"/> <button id="btn2">-</button> </li>';
    $("#ok").click(function(){
        var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
        //alert(number);
        for(var $j=i; $j<= number; $j++){
            $("ol").append(text);
            id++;i++;
        }
    });
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("ol").append(text);
        id++;i++;
    });

    $('.divi').on('click','#btn2',function(){
        //alert(id);
        var parent=$(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
        //alert(parent);
        var parent_im=$(this).parent().attr("id");
        //alert(parent_im);
        $("#"+parent_im).slideUp('medium',function(){
            $("#"+parent_im).remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="number" id="num" autofocus="true"></input>
<button id="ok">OK</button>
<br/><br/>
<button id="btn1">+</button>
<div class="divi">
<ol>
</ol>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Whichever '-' is clicked, the 1st box is removed.
I want to remove that particular box to which the '-' button is placed.
 Can anyone help me do this.
Thank You in advance

---

Edit: How can i delete the last row(textbox and ' - ' button) on click of a button which is placed next to the ' + ' ie,

```
<button id="btn1">+</button>
<button id="btndel">-</button>
```

Comment: first remove the ID of buttons since there is a chance to repeat the ID

Comment: if i remove the id how can i delete a particular box?

Comment: use class attribute instead

Comment: for button there is a single ID. 
List Items' id is wat is getting changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1jfz1cae/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    var id=1,text;
    text = '<li id="input_'+id+'" ><input type="text"/> <button class="btn2">-</button> </li>';
    $("#ok").click(function(){
        var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
        //alert(number);
        for(var $j=i; $j<= number; $j++){
            $("ol").append(text);
            id++;i++;
        }
    });
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("ol").append(text);
        id++;i++;
    });

    $('.divi').on('click','.btn2',function(){

        $(this).parents("li").slideUp('medium',function(){
            $(this).parents("li").remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="number" id="num" autofocus="true"></input>
<button id="ok">OK</button>
<br/><br/>
<button id="btn1">+</button>
<div class="divi">
<ol>
</ol>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me which option is not working ? @Poojanagarajrao

Comment: the ' - ' buttons associated with the text box; i mean its working differently. It shd remove the text box it is associated with, instead it is removing the 1st txt box.

Comment: ur version made the button inactive. it din delete the 1st box also

Comment: Thank You. It is working. Sorry, there was some other mistake when I tried  for the 1st time

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

```
$('input[id^=btn]').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){

      $(this).closest('input[type=text]').remove();

});
```

Comment: Replace `.unbind('click').bind` by `.on`

Comment: @amrit its not workin. even the 1st box is not getting removed

Comment: Please an a description or an explanation of what your code does.

Comment: clicking on ' + ' button adds a text box and a - button; or the number of boxes required can be specified using the number box; on clicking the ' - ' button, the text box associated with tat ' - ' shd be removed